# Python fillna based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby, fillna

I have the following dataframe grouped by datafile and I want to fillna(method ='bfill') only for those 'groups' that contain more than half of the data.

```
df.groupby('datafile').count()

datafile   column1   column2 column3 column4

datafile1     5         5       3       4         
datafile2     5         5       4       5
datafile3     5         5       5       5 
datafile4     5         5       0       0     
datafile5     5         5       1       1
```

As you can see in the df above, I'd like to fill those groups that contain most of the information but not those who has none or little information. So I was thinking in a condition something like fillna those who have more than half of the counts and don't fill the rest or those with less than half.

I'm struggling on how to set up my condition since it involves working with a result of a groupby and the original df.

Help is appreciated it.

example df:

```
index        datafile    column1   column2 column3 column4

0            datafile1      5       5        NaN      20         
1            datafile1      6       6        NaN      21         
2            datafile1      7       7        9        NaN         
3            datafile1      8       8        10       23         
4            datafile1      9       9        11       24         
5            datafile2      3       3        2        7         
6            datafile2      4       4        3        8         
7            datafile2      5       5        4        9         
8            datafile2      6       6        NaN      10         
9            datafile2      7       7        6        11         
10           datafile3      10      10       24       4         
11           datafile3      11      11       25       5         
12           datafile3      12      12       26       6         
13           datafile3      13      13       27       7         
14           datafile3      14      14       28       8         
15           datafile4      4       4        NaN      NaN         
16           datafile4      5       5        NaN      NaN         
17           datafile4      6       6        NaN      NaN         
18           datafile4      7       7        NaN      NaN         
19           datafile4      8       8        NaN      NaN         
19           datafile4      9       9        NaN      NaN         
20           datafile5      7       7        1        3  
21           datafile5      8       8        NaN      NaN         
22           datafile5      9       9        NaN      NaN         
23           datafile5      10      10       NaN      NaN         
24           datafile5      11      1        NaN      NaN
```

expected output df:

```
index        datafile    column1   column2 column3 column4

0            datafile1      5       5        9        20         
1            datafile1      6       6        9        21         
2            datafile1      7       7        9        23         
3            datafile1      8       8        10       23         
4            datafile1      9       9        11       24         
5            datafile2      3       3        2        7         
6            datafile2      4       4        3        8         
7            datafile2      5       5        4        9         
8            datafile2      6       6        6        10         
9            datafile2      7       7        6        11         
10           datafile3      10      10       24       4         
11           datafile3      11      11       25       5         
12           datafile3      12      12       26       6         
13           datafile3      13      13       27       7         
14           datafile3      14      14       28       8         
15           datafile4      4       4        NaN      NaN         
16           datafile4      5       5        NaN      NaN         
17           datafile4      6       6        NaN      NaN         
18           datafile4      7       7        NaN      NaN         
19           datafile4      8       8        NaN      NaN         
19           datafile4      9       9        NaN      NaN         
20           datafile5      7       7        1        3  
21           datafile5      8       8        NaN      NaN         
22           datafile5      9       9        NaN      NaN         
23           datafile5      10      10       NaN      NaN         
24           datafile5      11      1        NaN      NaN
```

Comment: could you show an example of df and what should be  the expected output

Comment: Added an example df and expected output.

Comment: Whether a group is filled in one column depends only on the NaN in that column for that group or also depends on the NaN in the other columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the proportion of NON-null values ​​is greater than or equal to 0.5 in each column then it is filled with the bfill method:

```
rate = 0.5
not_na = df.notna()
g = not_na.groupby(df['datafile'])
df_fill = (
    df.bfill()         
    .where(
        g.transform('sum')
        .div(g['datafile'].transform('size'), axis=0)
        .ge(rate) |
        not_na
    )
)
print(df_fill)
```

---

```
    index   datafile  column1  column2  column3  column4
0       0  datafile1        5        5      9.0     20.0
1       1  datafile1        6        6      9.0     21.0
2       2  datafile1        7        7      9.0     23.0
3       3  datafile1        8        8     10.0     23.0
4       4  datafile1        9        9     11.0     24.0
5       5  datafile2        3        3      2.0      7.0
6       6  datafile2        4        4      3.0      8.0
7       7  datafile2        5        5      4.0      9.0
8       8  datafile2        6        6      6.0     10.0
9       9  datafile2        7        7      6.0     11.0
10     10  datafile3       10       10     24.0      4.0
11     11  datafile3       11       11     25.0      5.0
12     12  datafile3       12       12     26.0      6.0
13     13  datafile3       13       13     27.0      7.0
14     14  datafile3       14       14     28.0      8.0
15     15  datafile4        4        4      NaN      NaN
16     16  datafile4        5        5      NaN      NaN
17     17  datafile4        6        6      NaN      NaN
18     18  datafile4        7        7      NaN      NaN
19     19  datafile4        8        8      NaN      NaN
20     19  datafile4        9        9      NaN      NaN
21     20  datafile5        7        7      1.0      3.0
22     21  datafile5        8        8      NaN      NaN
23     22  datafile5        9        9      NaN      NaN
24     23  datafile5       10       10      NaN      NaN
25     24  datafile5       11        1      NaN      NaN
```

Also we can  use:

```
m = (not_na.groupby(df['datafile'], sort=False)
           .sum()
           .div(df['datafile'].value_counts(), axis=0)
           .ge(rate)
           .reindex(df['datafile']).reset_index(drop=True))
df.bfill().where(m | not_na)
```

---

both methods have similar returns for the sample dataframe

```
%%timeit
rate = 0.5
not_na = df.notna()
m = (not_na.groupby(df['datafile'], sort=False)
           .sum()
           .div(df['datafile'].value_counts(),axis=0)
           .ge(rate)
           .reindex(df['datafile']).reset_index(drop=True))
df.bfill().where(m | not_na)
11.1 ms ± 53.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
rate = 0.5
not_na = df.notna()
g = not_na.groupby(df['datafile'])
df_fill = (df.bfill()
             .where(g.transform('sum').div(g['datafile'].transform('size'),
                                           axis=0).ge(rate) |
                      not_na)
            )
12.9 ms ± 225 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.groupby.filter`

```
def most_not_null(x): return x.isnull().sum().sum() < (x.notnull().sum().sum() // 2)

filtered_groups = df.groupby('datafile').filter(most_not_null)
df.loc[filtered_groups.index] = filtered_groups.bfill()
```

Output

```
>>> df
    index   datafile  column1  column2  column3  column4
0       0  datafile1        5        5      9.0     20.0
1       1  datafile1        6        6      9.0     21.0
2       2  datafile1        7        7      9.0     23.0
3       3  datafile1        8        8     10.0     23.0
4       4  datafile1        9        9     11.0     24.0
5       5  datafile2        3        3      2.0      7.0
6       6  datafile2        4        4      3.0      8.0
7       7  datafile2        5        5      4.0      9.0
8       8  datafile2        6        6      6.0     10.0
9       9  datafile2        7        7      6.0     11.0
10     10  datafile3       10       10     24.0      4.0
11     11  datafile3       11       11     25.0      5.0
12     12  datafile3       12       12     26.0      6.0
13     13  datafile3       13       13     27.0      7.0
14     14  datafile3       14       14     28.0      8.0
15     15  datafile4        4        4      NaN      NaN
16     16  datafile4        5        5      NaN      NaN
17     17  datafile4        6        6      NaN      NaN
18     18  datafile4        7        7      NaN      NaN
19     19  datafile4        8        8      NaN      NaN
20     19  datafile4        9        9      NaN      NaN
21     20  datafile5        7        7      1.0      3.0
22     21  datafile5        8        8      NaN      NaN
23     22  datafile5        9        9      NaN      NaN
24     23  datafile5       10       10      NaN      NaN
25     24  datafile5       11        1      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: good solution, usually `groupby.filter` can be slow compared to methods with `transforn` if the function is complex. However, it has the advantage that it does not use bfill in groups where it will be converted to NaN again. 
I think this method could have good performance too:)

Comment: Thanks @ansev. I know that filter can be slower due to iterations on groups internally. It slows down with increasing number of groups. Is there any simpler way to get number of `NaN` values in df than `x.isnull().sum().sum()`?

Comment: I think this is the best way to get the number of null, for number of not null we can do `df.count().sum()`